# space is required between number and unit name

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I am full newbie in VHDL and I try to compile programs from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9hya97kRJA

Here is the Makefile

```
GHDL=ghdl
FLAGS="--std=93"

all:
    @$(GHDL) -a $(FLAGS) --ieee=synopsys sevenseg_test.vhd sevenseg.vhd
    @$(GHDL) -e $(FLAGS) sevenseg_test
    @$(GHDL) -r $(FLAGS) sevenseg_test --wave=wave.ghw --stop-time=1us
```

Here is the file sevenseg_test.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity sevenseg_test is
end;

architecture sim of sevenseg_test is

component sevenseg is
    port(
    S : in unsigned(3 downto 0);
    segments : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
    );
end component;

signal S : unsigned(3 downto 0) := 4d"0";
signal segments : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

begin
dut : sevenseg port map(S, segments);
process begin
    for i in 0 to 15 loop
    S <= to_unsigned(i,4);
    wait for 10 ns;
    end loop;
    wait;
end process;

end sim;
```

First, I had this bug `sevenseg_test.vhd:3:10:error: unit "numeric_std" not found in library "ieee"` and I found that the solution is to add `--ieee=synopsys` in the command line on the Makefile. However I had to change the FLAGS from `std=08` to `--std=93` in order to make it works. But I have still this issue : `sevenseg_test.vhd:17:37:error: space is required between number and unit name`. When I check the line 17 row 37 it's between the 4 and the d in the code `signal S : unsigned(3 downto 0) := 4d"0";`. But it's normal to have `4d"0"` in a vhdl code. I guess, maybe it's because I changed `std=08` to `--std=93`. How can I solve the problem so as to compile the code ?

Comment: @mkrieger `d` is supported for decimal formatted bit string literals since VHDL 2008

Comment: You're wandering down an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) path. Go back to the original problem with the commands from Steven Bell's makefile. Show the command line it was executing when encountering the error. If package numeric_std is not found in library ieee there's an issue with your ghdl installation. It may be as simple as read permissions for object files or directories. Your readers would also need the first three lines output of ghdl --version to understand what's expected. `ghdl -a --std=08 sevenseg_test.vhd` works here.

Comment: Add the [tag:ghdl] tag to your question.

Comment: You can get make to echo the command before execution by removing the'@' (commercial at) from infront of $(GHDL). By genning up a sevenseg.vhd I got all the way to a gtk waveform without touching sevenseg_test.vhd as shown in your question using the makefile shown in the video.

Comment: @user16145658 first, thank you for your response ! I didn't know what is an XY Problem I have learnt something interesting. I added the ghld tag as you told me.

Comment: I have this : 
```ghdl -a "--std=08" sevenseg_test.vhd sevenseg.vhd
sevenseg_test.vhd:3:10:error: unit "numeric_std" not found in library "ieee"
sevenseg_test.vhd:8:21:error: entity 'sevenseg_test' was not analysed
make: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 1```

Do I have to change the owner of my ghdl package to $USER ?

Comment: ```(base) toto@Toto-SSD:~/vhdl$ ghdl --version```

```GHDL 0.37 (Ubuntu 0.37+dfsg-1ubuntu1) [Dunoon edition]
 Compiled with GNAT Version: 9.3.0
 mcode code generator
Written by Tristan Gingold.

Copyright (C) 2003 - 2020 Tristan Gingold.
GHDL is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.```

Comment: ghdl-0.37 is from 29 Feb 2020 (out of date, release 2.0 should be soon).  Check permissions for all the packages [files](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/ghdl-gcc_0.37+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html). Everything should be ugo+r and all the directories should be ugo+x. There are newer binary releases on the github site (ghdl/ghdl/releases, a release, assets) that aren't packaged. They have relative bin lib and include directories and are relocatable (install anywhere, bin in execution path).  The nightly builds are tested before being made available.